# PDO MSSQL error query on null

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to select rows from my database table, and I am getting an error stating that

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in..
```

Our connection to the database shows successful. Below is my php code:

```
<?php
   require_once("dbconn.php");
   $db = getConnection();

   $input_pid = "870104-07-5448";
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Pat WHERE PID ='$input_pid'";
   $stmt = $db->query($sql);
   $row = $stmt->fetchObject();
   echo $row->PID;
   echo $row->Name;
?>
```

This is the dbconn.php code:

```
function getConnection(){
try {
    $hostname = "busctrlctr-pc";
    $dbname   = "DispenserSystem";
    $username = "sa";
    $password = "123456";
    $db = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname", $username, $password);
    echo 'We are succesful to connect the database !!'.'<br>'; // successful word
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "connection failed problem is >> ". $e -> getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}
```

}

Can i know why I am getting this error. Thank you.

Comment: What is in `getConnection()`?

Comment: post your `dbconn.php` file code

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php Check this

Comment: Looks like your connection can not be established.

Comment: @b0s3 i have posted my db conn code in the question

Comment: @Jens i tried running the connection file only.. it works actually..

Comment: @AlexLooksSoSad i have posted the dbconn file as you stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never return `$db` in your funtion `getConnection()`;

change the funtion to:

```
function getConnection(){
try {
    $hostname = "busctrlctr-pc";
    $dbname   = "DispenserSystem";
    $username = "sa";
    $password = "123456";
    $db = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname", $username, $password);
    echo 'We are succesful to connect the database !!'.'<br>'; // successful word
    return $db;
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "connection failed problem is >> ". $e -> getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}
}
```